# Should it be on or over?

Tags: prepositions

From Aljazeera News:

> Saudi Arabia's foreign minister has said the kingdom is ready "to take necessary measures if needed" over Yemen's political crisis, after denouncing Iran's alleged role in the turmoil as an "act of aggression."

Can I use **on** in the place of **over**? For example: Saudi Arabia's foreign minister has said the kingdom is ready "to take necessary measures if needed" **on** Yemen's political crisis.

Comment: Either could probably be justified, but my own preference would be to use ***as regards***. But more importantly than that, the expression is tautological. The word *necessary* is synonymous with *needed*. So if the measures are *necessary*, clearly, by definition, they are *needed*. A better form would be simply *to take measures if needed*.

Comment: Necessity is the mother of intervention.

Comment: News copyreaders would aim for brevity.'on' or 'over' Yemen's political crisis sounds clunky to an English-speaker's ear--so does 'if needed'.

Comment: Better to say: The Kingdom is ready to take necessary measures to quell Yemen's political crisis'. No need to say 'if necessary' since the kingdom is ready to take necessary measures. 'Quell' means to suppress, put an end to..., extinguish.